# Rails not identifying haml - rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partial

I have a Rails 2.3.8 project running on Ruby (Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]).

I have a folder in app/views called uploads and it has haml file:

```
_files.html.haml
```

But when I try to call it using:

```
<%= render :partial =>  "/uploads/files"%>
```

is says:

> Missing template /uploads/_users.erb in view path app/views:vendor/plugins/devise-1.0.8/app/views

It appears to be that it tried to locate **.erb** (_users.erb) where as the file name is `_users.html.haml`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the below answer it was suggested this is a duplicate: [Generating Sass and Haml in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399780/generating-sass-and-haml-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the haml gem listed in your gemfile? I believe that's all that needs to be done.

Comment: yep thats it, I added config.gem "haml" to environment.rb and now its working thanks a lot

Comment: glad to help. Also, looks like this is a repeat, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399780/generating-sass-and-haml-in-rails

Comment: Today compatible version seems is haml 3.1.8